# bluetoothctl does not show a default controller on thinkpad X230

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I could not get my bluetooth to work.
`bluetoothctl` does not show a default controller and I was not able to find anything about it that would be of use.
I read the Arch Wiki and did `modprobe btusb`.
I activated the bluetoothd service by running the command `sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service --now`.
When I now run `bluetoothctl` it says "Agent registered".
But when I now run the `list` command, nothing shows up.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the issue.
I had my bluetooth device deactivated through BIOS settings.
I just had to enable it and everything worked.